# Show that the sequence $g_{n}$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function, arzela-ascoli

Given a sequence $f_{n}:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ of continuous functions, define $g_{n}:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by setting $g_{n}(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-x)^{1/3}}dt$; $x \in [0,1]$.
Show that the sequence $g_{n}$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

My attempt: To prove this result, we need to show $g_{n}$ is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded on $[0,1]$.

1. Equicontinuous:  For given $\epsilon>0$, there exist a $\delta >0$ such that if $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $|x-y|<\delta$, then

$|g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(y)|=|\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-x)^{1/3}}dt - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-y)^{1/3}}dt|\leq \int_{0}^{1} \frac{|f_{n}(t)|}{(t-x)^{1/3}}dt+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{|f_{n}(t)|}{(t-y)^{1/3}}dt$

Since, $f_{n}$ is continuous over compact set [0,1]. This implies $f_{n}$ is bounded over $[0,1]$. This implies there exist $M>0$ such that $|f_{n}(x)|\leq M$, for all $x \in [0,1]$.

$|g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(y)| \leq M[\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(t-x)^{1/3}}dt + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(t-y)^{1/3}}dt]$

Now I solved the improper integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(t-x)^{1/3}}dt= 3/2[(x-1)^{2/3}-x^{2/3}]$.

I am confused here, how can I write this in terms of $\epsilon$, so I can show the equicontinuous step. Can anyone please suggest me the last step of this question? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking to evaluate $g_n(x)-g_n(y)$, but you change the $-$ sign into $+$ while replacing $g_n(x)$ with its value.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.

Comment: Yes, but you should revisit that as it led   you in wrong directions.

Comment: It's false as stated. Take $f_n = n$ and then you have $g_n(0)= \int_0^1 nt^{-1/3} \to \infty.$

Comment: Can you explain your point, what I stated incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the $M$, just because $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions doesn't mean that it's converging to a continuous or bounded function.  We don't know anything about what $f_n$ is doing. 
You are absolutely right in saying that each $f_n$ is bounded because it's a continuous function on a compact set, however that doesn't mean all the $f_n$'s are bounded by the same $M$.

Take for example the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=nx$ this sequence is bounded for all $n$ on say $[0,1]$ but the bound depends upon $n$ and in the pointwise limit it  goes to infinity for $x\neq0$.

Comment: Yes. I understand. I think I need to take bound $M_{n}$ that depends on n.